# Teams Message Card - httpPOST not Working

Tags: postman, webhooks, microsoft-teams

Hello Good Developers,

I tried many answers from SO before posting my question here.
I am trying to use actionable Card in Microsoft Teams Message Card
[image: Screenshot of the Card]

if you click on Approve button an API URL should be hit.
in this API URL I've added `200 Response` with
`'CARD-ACTION-STATUS' => 'Approved',`

But When I click on the button it says

`Could not complete the requested action. Please try again later.`

Here's the JSON I am using

```
{
  "summary": "Card \"Test card\"",
  "themeColor": "0078D7",
  "title": "Card created: \"Name of card\"",
  "sections": [
    {
      "activityTitle": "David Claux",
      "activitySubtitle": "9/13/2016, 3:34pm",
      "activityImage": "https://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/MSC12_Oscar_002.jpg",
      "facts": [
        {
          "name": "Board:",
          "value": "Testing Board"
        }
      ],
      "text": "Lorem ipsum"
    }
  ],
  "potentialAction": [
    {
        "@type": "HttpPOST",
        "name": "Approve",
        "target": "https://example.com/test-post?ID=7d66186f-ee1a-4612-a4c7-5c2099758db0",
        "body": "Test Body",
        "headers": [
            {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried so many online resources but unable to figure out what am I missing.
I am posting this JSON via POSTMAN and once done, I'll be posting this JSON via my Laravel APP

May I know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please try to  update your message card  "potentialAction": [
    {
 '@type': 'ActionCard',
"name": "Approve",
  "actions": [
                     {      
       "@type": "HttpPOST",
        "name": "Approve",
        "target": "https://example.com/test-post?ID=7d66186f-ee1a-4612-a4c7-5c2099758db0",
        "body": "Test Body",
        "headers": [
            {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
        ]
}]. Please let me know if this doesn't help you.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT I tried the exact payload you suggested but still, I am getting the same error `Could not complete the requested action. Please try again later`
Here's what I received in response in webconsole
`{"status":"Failed","actionId":"dbd4484a-3037-41e5-8d39-13b3226cb099","properties":{"displayMessage":"<p>Could not complete the requested action. Please try again later.</p>\n","errorCode":"ODataContentTypeException"}}`

Comment: Can you add another webhook and test just to see if you are getting the same error?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I tried this with a new webhook but still getting the same error

Comment: @PankajJha- Just to isolate the issue, could you please set the target URL to one of the URLs generated on https://webhook.site and see if it's hitting when you click on Approve? I just tried again and it's working fine.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT - I am still not able to hit the webhook on Approve.
here's a screencast for the same: 

https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2I0l2S0j341r083U352Y/Screen%20Recording%202019-10-09%20at%2009.56.36.08%20PM.mp4

I don't understand if you are able to do it, why it isn't executing at my end?

Comment: @PankajJha Could you please try setting the target URL to one of the URLs generated on [webhook.site](https://webhook.site/) and see if the request reaches there. I could see some issue when I tried your target URL but I could not repro it when I changed the URL.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT - I did exactly what `Wajeed` and `you` suggested.
If you can see video link in my previous comment, you can see I have added URL from webhook.site but still its not working.
Here's the JSON Payload I am using to generate notification - https://jsonblob.com/90789c33-f684-11e9-b5da-b7979f68f3aa

And here's the webhook URL where I am sendig the POST hit
https://outlook.office.com/webhook/8cc08659-8d48-4b7a-aa56-e3721a2e079a@e24e70de-a391-4c09-9140-90bcdfc15f42/IncomingWebhook/bf9e581c81ef446e95c693c75fbd4af3/f8f01fb5-2bbb-41a2-b526-982c3a299a02

Comment: I believe the issue is the missing card type. You need to add "@type": "MessageCard" as a top level field. You can try out your card (and see any json errors) here: https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: @AndrewClear - I am pushing this notification via Incoming Webhook, so far what my understanding is that adaptive cards don't work with webhook.
When I run your suggested JSON it says `Summary or Text is required`. When I add summary at the top level, I get a blank notification.
However, I saw 1 hit from your end at webhook.site - may I know what JSON payload have you used and can I use it with incoming webhook?

Comment: The message card playground has legacy samples as well, use the drop down on the top left. I used your payload, and just added that one field.

Comment: @AndrewClear - I did exactly what you suggested here are the screencasts
https://www.screencast.com/t/EoHXZtlc
https://www.screencast.com/t/tQCI6rrFfhN

And here's the updated JSON
https://jsonblob.com/0cc42805-fc17-11e9-b6a0-5b42cd5fcd26

still no result...

Comment: Can it be an issue with headers? as so far I am not sending headers like authorization, card-correlation-id, action-request-id etc: https://www.screencast.com/t/lndfQpVUu8

do you think this might be the problem?

Comment: The headers don't seem to be sending through as far as I can tell. I was able to get a 404 error by removing them entirely. Still doesn't seem to be working as expected though

Comment: @PankajJha Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @TaylorClark No, I tried everything from above comments but nothing worked for me